# Tag chaos: [each], [.each], [jquery-each] and [for]

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, retag-request

We have 3 tags related to *"each"* on stackoverflow:

- [each](/questions/tagged/each) - This is used for the jQuery each function
- [.each](/questions/tagged/.each) - This is also used for the jQuery .each function
- [jquery-each](/questions/tagged/jquery-each) - Also refering to the jQuery .each function

I think that they all need to be changed. First of all, we need to remove the [.each](/questions/tagged/.each) tag, because that not a great name for it and causes to much indistinctness.
Secondly, the [each](/questions/tagged/each) tag needs to be more generic. If you look at the questions tagged with it, you can already see that people are using this for ruby, sass, ect. each loops instead of the specific jQuery each function. Questions which are tagged with the [each](/questions/tagged/each) tag and talk about the `jQuery.each` function should be retagged with the [jquery-each](/questions/tagged/jquery-each) tag.

Moreover, an `each` loop is called a `for` loop in some languages. I think the [for-loop](/questions/tagged/for-loop) and [each](/questions/tagged/each) don't differ and should by a synonyms.

Comment: Well, there's a `for` loop and a `foreach` loop, and likely what happens there is they add a space so that both the [tag:for] and [tag:each] tags get added, rather than the *appropriate* [tag:foreach] tag. The [tag:each] tag needs to be gone in the end.

Comment: I don't think it should be a tag at all. Most problems tagged each are not with how each works but about using it. It does not help narrow down the problem at all.

Comment: More tag chaos: there is also a tag called [tag:for-in-loop] which is just an equivalent of a `foreach` loop. And a [tag:do-loop] tag which is an equivalent of a `while` loop.